# Cast arbitrary escaped character to int

Tags: java, casting, escaping

I have a method that, at the end, takes a character array (with one element), and returns the cast of that character:

```
char[] first = {'a'};
return (int)first[0];
```

However, sometimes I have character arrays with two elements, where the first is always a "\" (i.e. it is a character array that "contains" an escaped character):

```
char second = {'\\', 'n'};
```

I would like to return `(int)'\n'`, but I do not know how to convert that array into a single escaped character. I am okay checking whether or not the array is of length 1 or 2, but I really don't want to have a long switch or if/else block to go through every possible escaped character.

Answer (score 1):

How about making an HashMap of escape character vs the second ? like:

```
Map<Character, int> escapeMap = new HashMap<>();
escapeMap.put('n', 10);
```

Then make something like:

```
If (second[0] == '\\') {
 return escapeMap.get(second[1]);
}
else
{
  return (int)first[0];
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except that `HashMap<String, int>` needs to be `<Character, Integer>`.  And `'\'` won't compile;  it needs to be `'\\'`.  And the type should be `Map<Character, Integer>` instead of HashMap.

Comment: It's interesting- my friend, who has the same issue as I, actually implemented this solution. If there's a better way to do it (i.e. without making a new Object, just using the array), I'd like to hear it, but there's a good chance yours is the best solution.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear:   primitives as generic types *will not compile* in Java.  You *cannot* write `Map<char, int>`.   But you can (and should) write `Map<Character, Integer>`.  Also, a variable's type should never be HashMap, it should be Map;  you should always refer to an object by its contract, not its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map to store the escape sequences mappings to their corresponding characters. If you assume that the escape sequence will always be just one character with the code below 128, you could simplify the mappings to something like this:

```
char[] escaped = {..., '\n', ...'\t', ...}
```

where the character `'\n'` is on the `(int)'n'`-th position of the array.

Then you would find the the escaped character just by `escaped[(int)second[1]]`. You just need to check the array bounds, if an invalid escape sequence is found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly hack. This works for me, but appears to be unreliable, buggy and time-consuming (and hence don't use this in critical parts).

```
char[] second = {'\\','n'};
String s = new String(second);
//write the String to an OutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos));
writer.write("key=" + s);
writer.close();
//load the String using Properties
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(bais);
baos.close();
bais.close();
//now get the character
char c = prop.getProperty("key").charAt(0);
System.out.println((int)c);
```

output: 10 (which is the output of `System.out.println((int)'\n');`)

Answer (score 0):

When printing `(int)'a'` the decimal value of that character from the `UniCode` table is being printed. In the case of `a` that would be `93`. http://unicode-table.com/en/

`\n` is being identified as (Uni)code `LF` which means Line Feed or New Line. In the Unicode table thats the same as decimal number 10. Which indeed gets printed if you write: `System.out.println((int)'\n');`

Same goes for the characters `\b` , `\f` , `\r` , `\t' ,`\'`,`\"`and \\` which have special meaning for the compiler and have a special character code like `LF` for `\n`. Look them up if you want to know the details.

In that light the most simplest solution would be:

```
    char[] second = {'\\', 'n'};
    if (second.length > 1) {
        System.out.println((int)'\n');
    } else {
        System.out.println(second[0]);
    }
```

and thats only if `\n` is the only `escape sequence` you encounter.